# Set webpart visibility based on page category in Kentico

Tags: kentico

I have a page with a static HTML web part and want to set its visibility based on the value of the page category. If the category = "ABC" then make it visible, if not make it invisible. The category value was set through the Properties tab. I've tried these 2 macro below, but both didn't work. Thanks for your help!

```
{%if(CurrentDocument.Categories.DisplayNames=="ABC"){ return true; } else { return false; } #%}
```

or

```
{%if(CurrentDocument.Categories.DisplayNames.Contains("ABC")){ return true; } else { return false; } #%}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the following macro (and there is no need for IF condition):

```
{% CurrentDocument.IsInCategories("ABC;ABCD") %}
```

Multiple categories can be listed with a semicolon.